# Ruby on Rails. Bundler. Cucumber. rake aborted! Command failed with status (1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, bundler

I have a problem using Bundler and Cucumber with Rails 3.

When I run `$ rake cucumber` I get the following output:

```
bundle exec /usr/local/bin/ruby -I "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-
0.8.5/lib:lib" "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-0.8.5/bin/cucumber"  --profile default
(in /home/<username>/practice/rails/blog)
Using the default profile...
UUUU

1 scenario (1 undefined)
4 steps (4 undefined)
0m1.552s

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given /^a post$/ do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

Given /^a name was specified$/ do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

When /^I save the post$/ do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

Then /^the post should be saving$/ do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [bundle exec /usr/local/bin/ruby -I "/usr/l...]
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:993:in `block in sh'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1008:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1008:in `sh'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1092:in `sh'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-0.8.5/lib/cucumber/rake/task.rb:72:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-0.8.5/lib/cucumber/rake/task.rb:142:in `block in define_task'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:595:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:605:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:594:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:581:in `invoke'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2041:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2013:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1992:in `run'
/usr/local/bin/rake:31:in `'
```

Despite this output my features works fine and when I add step definitions and pass them all the changes are displayed in a console correctly.

Here's my Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>= 2.0.0.beta.22'
  gem 'Selenium'
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'webrat'
end
```

I want to note, if I use the `bundle exec cucumber` or `cucumber features/` commands I don't get any error messages.

What is the reason of this issue? How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.6;

Ruby 1.9.2;

Ruby on Rails 3.0.0;

Bundler 1.0.0;

Cucumber 0.8.5;

Cucumber-Rails 0.3.2.

Answer (score 5):

I am also seeing the same problem. With a little hunting I could figure where this error is coming but still don't know how to fix it.

The issue is that the "bundle exec ..." shell call is exiting with status code "1". That is an error for the rake.rb script and therefore it is throwing those lines. Looks like it is some kind of a false alarm only.

Also, this happens only when all the scenarios pass. If there is even a single failure, you will not see this error.

Comment: If you've already found the problem in the source code, then you should definitely report it as a bug on cucumber. :)

Comment: Turns out it's the --strict designation in the cucumber.yml and undefined tasks. See the bug that was opened here: https://rspec.lighthouseapp.com/projects/16211/tickets/680-rake-cucumber-throws-an-error-after-running-all-the-scenarios#ticket-680-1