# cucumber, rake aborted, command failed with status 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

The problem with cucumber on Rails 3.

This is looks similar to [Ruby on Rails. Bundler. Cucumber. rake aborted! Command failed with status (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740523/ruby-on-rails-bundler-cucumber-rake-aborted-command-failed-with-status-1) but with some difference.
After running `rake cucumber:wip` i got this:

```
bundle exec /home/megas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby -I "/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/cucumber-0.10.0/lib:lib" "/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/cucumber-0.10.0/bin/cucumber"  --profile wip
Using the wip profile...
no such file to load -- nokogiri (LoadError)
/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/cucumber-rails-0.3.2/lib/cucumber/web/tableish.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/home/megas/Work/strawberries/features/support/env.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/cucumber-0.10.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load'
/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/cucumber-0.10.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load_code_file'
/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/cucumber-0.10.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:176:in `load_file'
/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/cucumber-0.10.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:78:in `block in load_files!'
/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/cucumber-0.10.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:77:in `each'
/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/cucumber-0.10.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:77:in `load_files!'
/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/cucumber-0.10.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:137:in `load_step_definitions'
/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/cucumber-0.10.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:39:in `run!'
/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/cucumber-0.10.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/cucumber-0.10.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/home/megas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/cucumber-0.10.0/bin/cucumber:14:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [bundle exec /home/megas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1...]
```

My Gemfile

```
gem 'nifty-generators'
gem 'database_cleaner'
gem 'cucumber-rails'
gem 'cucumber'
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'spork'
gem 'launchy'
gem 'machinist', '>= 2.0.0.beta1'
gem 'faker'
```

The differences are: using rvm 1.2.0, it doesn't work at all, error message difference begins at "no such file to load -- nokogiri (LoadError)"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding nokogiri in your Gemfile and run `bundle install`

If that does not work, update your question and add your env.rb file and your Gemfile.lock