# What is a cucumber #source_tag ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, rake

I'm having this issue with cucumber when. Here is everything.

#### My Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

gem 'pg'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :test do 
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

#### Feature Test

```
Feature: Requesting invitations
  As a visitor
  I want to request a beta invitation
  So I can be sent an invitation when the site is ready

  Scenario: Requesting an invitation
    Given I am on the homepage
    When I request and invitation for "foo@example.com"
    Then I should see "Your on the list" confirmation
```

#### Error output

```
    Feature: Requesting invitations
      As a visitor
      I want to request a beta invitation
      So I can be sent an invitation when the site is ready

      Scenario: Requesting an invitation
        Given I am on the homepage
        When I request and invitation for "foo@example.com"
        Then I should see "Your on the list" confirmation

rake cucumber:ok
/Users/node/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber  --profile default
Using the default profile...
Feature: Requesting invitations
  As a visitor
  I want to request a beta invitation
  So I can be sent an invitation when the site is ready

  Scenario: Requesting an invitation                    # features/requesting_invitations.feature:6
Deprecated: please use #source_tags instead.
    Given I am on the homepage                          # features/requesting_invitations.feature:7
      Undefined step: "I am on the homepage" (Cucumber::Undefined)
      features/requesting_invitations.feature:7:in `Given I am on the homepage'
    When I request and invitation for "foo@example.com" # features/requesting_invitations.feature:8
      Undefined step: "I request and invitation for "foo@example.com"" (Cucumber::Undefined)
      features/requesting_invitations.feature:8:in `When I request and invitation for "foo@example.com"'
    Then I should see "Your on the list" confirmation   # features/requesting_invitations.feature:9
      Undefined step: "I should see "Your on the list" confirmation" (Cucumber::Undefined)
      features/requesting_invitations.feature:9:in `Then I should see "Your on the list" confirmation'

1 scenario (1 undefined)
3 steps (3 undefined)
0m0.967s

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

Given /^I am on the homepage$/ do
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

When /^I request and invitation for "([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

Then /^I should see "([^"]*)" confirmation$/ do |arg1|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/node/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bi...]

Tasks: TOP => cucumber:ok
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

So as you can see for some reason it's breaking when I run this rake task. I get the same thing when I run 'rake cucumber' I don't know what a #source_tag is and wasn't able to find documentation on it. How can I fix this and remove the error? I thought this was a pretty straight forward scenario. Gem list gives:

```
cucumber (1.1.8)
cucumber-rails (1.3.0)
```

Thanks. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Ok figured it out. I found this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740523/ruby-on-rails-bundler-cucumber-rake-aborted-command-failed-with-status-1

Comment: Still however, I don't know what the deprecation warning was from.

Comment: Ok and looks like I found out what tags are here https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The #source_tag warning is really meant for the capybara devs.  Capybara is a dependency of cucumber-rails.

(*Hint, this is a great time to trim down that Gemfile... every bit helps.*)

As seen within the [cucumber github issues](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/232)

> Really, the deprecation warning is intended to be shown to the Capybara developers, so it doesn't make sense for you as a Cucumber user to see it. I guess we should just remove the deprecation warnings altogether, unless someone can think of a clever mechanism to only show it to Capybara devs when they're running their tests. @aslakhellesoy @joliss @jnicklas WDYT?

...

> Cucumber 1.1.9 has been released, removing the warnings.

**tl;dr** upgrade to `cucumber` >= 1.1.9 and the #source_tag distraction will go away.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the 'source_tags' message means but it is a warning rather than an error.  The real problem appears to be that Cucumber hasn't found any step definitions.  You'll need to write the step definitions, Cucumber should give you the code to start with - it usually prints the 'snippets' immediately after the summary of results.